# setuid bit has different behavior depending on the directory

Tags: linux, c, setuid

I've been testing the setuid permission, and I am having some trouble to making it work.

Let's say I am doing the tests with two user `owneruser` and `otheruser`.

I've written a simple c program that all it does is call `system()` to display the current user.

testid.c:

```
int main(void)
{
  setresgid(222, 222, 222); // To simplify, this numbers represent just harcoded 
  setresuid(222, 222, 222); // values for the owneruser id and owneruser group id

  system("whoami");
}
```

User `owneruser` compiles the program to two different directories and sets the setuid bit, one that `owneruser` owns and the other for the example to the `/tmp` directory, the commands look something like:

```
gcc testid.c -o /tmp/testid
gcc testid.c -o /home/owneruser/testid

chmod 4755 /tmp/testid
chmod 4755 /home/owneruser/testid
```

Now when `otheruser` runs the programs, in `/home/owneruser/testid` I get the output:

```
owneruser
```

and in `/tmp/testid` I get the output:

```
otheruser
```

What is causing this different behavior?

Comment: Can you post the output of `mount | grep /tmp`?

Comment: @user2313067 I see now, the output is: `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)`